# Best approach to writing a network class

Tags: java, android

I want to write a class that handles all my network interaction called `NetworkManager`. So using an instance of this class I'd have something like:

```
NetworkManager nm = new NetworkManager();
...
nm.login(username, password);
...
```

However, what is the best approach so this network manager can do something on the UI thread once some response has been received? Modelling on a onClick style event I think this would be like:

```
nm.getPicture(new NetworkListener() {
    @Override
    public void run(Picture p){
        updateUI(p);
    }
```

Where I am unsure how to write the `getPicture` method and the NetworkListener() class.

I don't want to use `AsyncTask`, because this would mean I'd have to write the server code at different parts of the MainActivity. I have also considered a broadcaster and a listener, but this seems too much for a one off event.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html. The official documentation recommends using an AsyncTask. That doesn't mean that all the networking code must be in this AsyncTask though. Nothing prevents you from just delegating to your NetworkManager inside the AsyncTask.

Comment: I think AsyncTask is mandatory. Then you could use a listener to inform your activity/fragment that the operation is finished. Use different method to call different event, like onLoginSuccessful, onLoginUnsuccessfull, onConnectionError, etc.

Comment: My problem is that I'm using an Asynchronous Http Client (jloops) already. So I just want to be able to call a method on the client in `NetworkManager` and then the result event from that to trigger some kind of UI interaction on the MainActivity. I suppose I could not use jloops and code all the server stuff myself, having every server interaction in `NetworkManager` blocking the thread it time, then using AsyncTask for every server interation. This is quite heavy though, since then I'd need a separate AsyncTasks, for all the different server interations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout Retrofit (http://square.github.io/retrofit/) it might be useful to consider for integrating the part of your network class. I'm not sure if you will have multiple similar calls, but if so, I would advice you to apply the Observer pattern, where you make the call and wait for the response asynchronously, yet, there's a nice library to accomplish that, very well documented, called Otto (http://square.github.io/otto/).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but is there not a way to do this using a handle, rather than resorting to a third party library?

Comment: sure, you can do it all by hand of course..to the Observer pattern, you can just provide means for "listeners" to subscribe for events on your Network class, eg. addListener(YourOwnListenerInterfaceType) which adds to a Set...then whenever you want to dispatch a network event you just loop over the Listeners in your set and call the method you specified in your listener...the classes that you call addListener, will receive it. Let me know you you want it more detailed.

Comment: I think I'm going to use AsyncTask with a NetworkManager that blocks the thread for network operations, having a lot of listeners sounds complicated for what I'm trying. One thing though, I want actions to be queued on the object. So if I call mNetworkManager.login(), then mNetworkManager.upload() it does them in this order. Could you let me know what the best way of approach this is?

Comment: You can setup a "executor" and configure it as a SingleThreadedExecutor..read more on the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html   basically with this Executor you will be sure that all the requests you add will be executed in series.